# Associate elements of an array as the type of a property Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

Is there a way to assign the type of a property as the elements of an array? I have the following class:

```
class SomeClass {
  color: 'red' | 'blue';
}
```

Is there a way to create an array with the allowed colors and assign it to `color` type?

```
class SomeClass {
  color: *some way to get "'red' | 'blue'" from allowedColors*;
  allowedColors = ['red', 'blue'];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `allowedColors = ['red', 'blue']` will infer the type of `allowedColors` to be `string[]`, using a trick similar to [an old workaround for string based enums](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/literal-types.html) we can convince the compiler to type it as `('red'|'blue')[]` once we have this we can type `color` as having the same type as an element of that array:

```
function arrayTypeHelper<T extends string>(o: Array<T>): T[] {
  return o;
}

class SomeClass {
  static allowedColors = arrayTypeHelper(['red', 'blue']);
  color: typeof SomeClass.allowedColors[0]; // 'red' | 'blue'
}
```

Or if we don't want to use `arrayTypeHelper` in multiple places we can just do:

```
class SomeClass2 {
  static readonly allowedColors = (<T extends string>(o: T[]) => o)(['red', 'blue']);
  color: typeof SomeClass.allowedColors[0]; // 'red' | 'blue'
}
```

**Note** I changed `allowedColors` to be `static` and `readonly` as based on the question the field should probably not be mutable and is the same for all instances of the class. Also this is necessary to do the relative typing.

**Note 2** While this solution works within the constraint of your current design, maybe you should have a look at [string based enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's most common way you declare color to be an enum, and allowedColors should read the allowed values from the enum:

```
enum Color {
    red,
    blue,
}

private allowedColors: Color[] = Object.keys(Color).map(key => Color[key]);
private color: Color = allowedColors[0];
```